# Origin of the personal pronouns

Tags: etymology, personal-pronouns

What is the origin of the personal pronouns *I*, *you*, *he*, *she*, *it*, *we*, and *they*?

Comment: I would advance a guess, and say that they all originates from PIE.

Comment: @Eldros is referring to Proto-Indo European (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language).

Comment: I would have thought pie was the origin of "mine." Pies are quite tasty and oughtn't be shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't got time to take them all the way (or to check references, so this is from memory), but yes they do go back to PIE, with the possible exception of *she*. But they come by different routes.

- *I* from Old English *ic*, ultimately from PIE *eghom*.
- *You* is historically the object case of *ye*, cognate with German *euch*, and Sanskrit *yuyam*. Note that these are plural: the singular *thou* has dropped out of use in most English dialects.
- *He* is certainly common Germanic (Cf Swedish *hän*) and I think it goes back to the same root as Latin *is*.
- *She* is another word that came in after the Old English period, but I think it's cognate with German *sie*. I'm not sure of its earlier history.
- *We* is also Germanic (German *wir*), but I don't recall its older history offhand.
- *They* is Old Norse, and replaced Old English *hie*. It goes back to the same demonstrative root as *that*.

I hope somebody has time to expand my random recollections.

Comment: That is broadly in line with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_pronouns